# Problema com HttpWebResponse. Não responde

Tags: c#, http, request, webrequest

Espero que possam me ajudar, estou com um problema quando tento via [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) fazer uma requisição em meu servidor ( a requisição é lenta, demora cerca de 10 minutos para ser processada e retornada )

Para requisições rápidas funciona tudo normal, para requisições lentas ( mais de 10 minutos ) o c# não identifica que houve uma resposta do servidor http.

O estranho é que o mesmo código no servidor se diminuído o loop funciona, então o problema é o `c#` pois identifico no banco de dados que todo o ciclo do servidor http foi concluído e retornado

### Código:

```
        Request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create( url );
        Request.Method = "get";
        Request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        Request.CookieContainer = Cookie;
        Request.KeepAlive = false;
        Request.ContentLength = 0;
        Request.Timeout = 20 * ( 1000 * 60 ); // minutos
        Request.ReadWriteTimeout = 20 * ( 1000 * 60 ); // minutos
        Request.Proxy = null;

        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse) Request.GetResponse();
        Stream ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader ResponseReader = new StreamReader( ResponseStream );

        bufferResponse = ResponseReader.ReadToEnd();

        Response.Close();
        ResponseStream.Close();
        ResponseReader.Close();

        return ( bufferResponse );
```

Já tentei usar os comandos:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

E não ajudaram.

Comment: Pra qual endereço você está fazendo a requisição?

Comment: Boa tarde parceiro. É um servidor próprio, mas fiz um teste nele para verificar se realmente era no c# o problema e é sim. Quando uso o código : sleep(10); echo "OK"; Ele me retorna OK no c# após 10 segundos, mas se faço sleep(900); echo "OK"; o c# não responde mesmo após os 15 minutos